# Why it isn't possible to declare a method parameter as var type

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder why it is not possible a method parameter as var type like

```
private void myMethod(var myValue) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: because var is not a type.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: Or any dynamically typed language, really. It's not specific to Python.

Comment: @musicfreak: Or a language with better type inference. You don't need to abandon static typing just to avoid spelling out the types of function arguments.

Comment: Exactly. "var" in C# is not equivalent to value based type morphing in Python, Perl, etc. It is compile time and results in much more efficient code. There is a significant difference.

Comment: if you need it dynamically take C# 4.0 and the type dynamic or try your luck with object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only use [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) for variables inside the method body. Also the variable must be assigned at declaration and it must be possible to deduce the type unambiguously from the expression on the right-hand side.

In all other places you must specify a type, even if a type could in theory be deduced.

The reason is due to the way that the compiler is designed. A simplified description is that it first parses everything except method bodies and then makes a full analysis of the static types of every class, member, etc. It then uses this information when parsing the method bodies, and in particular for deducing the type of local variables declared as `var`. If `var` were allowed anywhere then it would require a large change to the way the compiler works.

You can read Eric Lippert's article on this subject for more details:

- [Why no var on fields?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-no-var-on-fields)

Comment: Why is this marked an answer? It describes what the OP already knows, but not the underlying limitation in C#'s type system.

Comment: Well it does answer his question

Answer (score 7):

Because the compiler determines the actual type by looking at the right hand side of the assignment. For example, here it is determined to be a string:

```
var s = "hello";
```

Here it is determined to be `Foo`:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

In method arguments, there is no "right hand side of the assignment", so you can't use var.

Comment: +1: Yes, 's' is declared and initialized once, methods can be called from multiple places in code, which of those should be used to infer the type of the arguement?

Answer (score 7):

Please see Juliet's answer for a better answer to this question.

Because it was too hard to add full type inference to C#.
Other languages such as Haskell and ML can automatically infer the most general type without you having to declare it.

The other answers state that it's "impossible" for the compiler to infer the type of var but actually it is possible in principle. For example:

```
abstract void anotherMethod(double z, double w);

void myMethod<T>(T arg)
{
    anotherMethod(arg, 2.0); // Now a compiler could in principle infer that arg must be of type double (but the actual C# compiler can't)
}
```

Have "var" method parameters is in principle the same thing as generic methods:

```
void myMethod<T>(T arg)
{
    ....
}
```

It is unfortunate that you can't just use the same syntax for both but this is probably due to the fact that that C#'s type inference was added only later.

In general, subtle changes in the language syntax and semantics can turn a "deterministic" type inference algorithm into an undecidable one.

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that your counter example is rather limited? It doesn't take operator overloading into account (as you correctly mention) and nothing dictates that a similar statement is always present..

Comment: yes this is why seemingingly "nice" things to have like implicit type conversions and operator overloading can make the type inference algorithm much harder. This is why, for example in ML, there are no implicit type conversions. To do type inference correctly, you have to design it into the language from the beginning.

Comment: But you can't actually write the code in your first example, because the compiler cannot say at compile time that arg * 2.0 will be legal. Unless this has changed in C# 4, this example won't compile. As for C# 3,  you get `Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'double'`

Comment: Anthony that's missing my point. Of course my example is not valid C#. For one thing: it is using var as the type of a method parameter! I also didn't finish the method body. I was only trying to explain how in principle a compiler might infer the type of a method parameter. Juliet's answer is the best explanation.

Comment: I've amended the answer to get rid of the operator overloading red-herring, and hopefully have clarified that it's not valid C# anyway even when using generic parameter syntax.

Answer (score 7):

See the [posting by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) about why var is not allowed on fields, which also contains the explanation why it doesn't work in method signatures:

> Let me give you a quick oversimplification of how the C# compiler works. First we run through every source file and do a "top level only" parse. That is, we identify every namespace, class, struct, enum, interface, and delegate type declaration at all levels of nesting. We parse all field declarations, **method declarations**, and so on. In fact, we parse everything except method bodies; those, we skip and come back to them later.
>   [...]
>    if we have "var" fields then the type of the field cannot be determined until the expression is analyzed, and that happens after we already need to know the type of the field.

Answer (score 6):

ML, Haskell, Scala, F#, SML, and other languages can easily figure out the type from equivalent expressions in their own language, mainly because they were designed with type-inference in mind from the very start. C# wasn't, its type-inference was tacked on as a post-hoc solution to the problem of accessing anonymous types.

I speculate that true Hindley-Milner type-inference was never implemented for C# because its complicated to deduce types in a language so dependent on classes and inheritance. Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Base { public void Print() { ... } }

class Derived1 : Base { }

class Derived2 : Base { }
```

And now I have this method:

```
var create() { return new Derived1(); }
```

What's the return type here? Is it `Derived1`, or should it be `Base`? For that matter, should it be `object`?

Ok, now lets say I have this method:

```
void doStuff(var someBase) { someBase.Print(); }

void Main()
{
    doStuff(new Derived1());
    doStuff(new Derived2()); // <-- type error or not?
}
```

The first call, `doStuff(new Derived1())`, presumably forces `doStuff` to the type `doStuff(Derived1 someBase)`. Let's assume for now that we infer a concrete type instead of a generic type `T`.

What about the second call, `doStuff(new Derived1())`? Is it a type error, or do we generalize to `doStuff<T>(T somebase) where T : Base` instead? What if we made the same call in a separate, unreferenced assembly -- the type inference algorithm would have no idea whether to use the narrow type or the more genenarlized type. So we'd end up with two different type signatures based on whether method calls originate from inside the assembly or a foreign assembly.

You can't generalize wider types based on usage of the function. You basically need to settle on a single concrete type as soon as you know which concrete type is being pass in. So in the example code above, unless you explicitly cast up to the Base type, `doStuff` is constrained to accept types of `Derived1` and the second call is a type error.

Now the trick here is settling on a type. What happens here:

```
class Whatever
{
    void Foo() { DoStuff(new Derived1()); } 
    void Bar() { DoStuff(new Derived2()); }
    void DoStuff(var x) { ... }
}
```

What's the type of `DoStuff`? For that matter, we know based on the above that one of the `Foo` or `Bar` methods contain a type error, but can you tell from looking which has the error?

Its not possible to resolve the type without changing the semantics of C#. In C#, order of method declaration has no impact on compilation (or at least it shouldn't ;) ). You might say instead that the method declared first (in this case, the `Foo` method) determines the type, so `Bar` has an error.

This works, but it also changes the semantics of C#: changes in method order will change the compiled type of the method.

But let's say we went further:

```
// Whatever.cs
class Whatever
{
    public void DoStuff(var x);
}

// Foo.cs
class Foo
{
    public Foo() { new Whatever().DoStuff(new Derived1()); }
}

// Bar.cs
class Bar
{
    public Bar() { new Whatever().DoStuff(new Derived2()); }
}
```

Now the methods is being invoked from different files. What's the type? Its not possible to decide without imposing some rules on compilation order: if Foo.cs gets compiled before Bar.cs, the type is determined by Foo.cs.

While we *can* impose those sorts of rules on C# to make type inference work, it would drastically change the semantics of the language.

By contrast, ML, Haskell, F#, and SML support type inference so well *because* they have these sorts of restrictions: you can't call methods before they're declared, the first method call to inferred functions determines the type, compilation order has an impact on type inference, etc.

Comment: tl;dr version: true Hindley-Milner type inference imposes restrictions on source code which would change the semantics of C#.

Comment: This is the best answer. I wish there was a way to transfer the votes from my answer to yours.

Answer (score 1):

The "var" keyword is used in C# and VB.NET for **type inference** - you basically tell the C# compiler: "you figure out what the type is".

"var" is still strongly typed - you're just too lazy yourself to write out the type and let the compiler figure it out - based on the data type of the right-hand side of the assignment.

Here, in a method parameter, the compiler has no way of figuring out what you really meant. How? What type did you really mean? There's no way for the compiler to infer the type from the method definition - therefore it's not a valid statement.

Comment: The compiler can infer the type, it's just more work. The compiler would look at how the type is used inside the method body, or alternately look at what's passed in by callers, then figure out the type.

Comment: I'd expand that as "you figure out what type it is, but it should be blatently obvious".

Comment: Languages like ML, Haskell, OCaml, Scala, F#, and other type-inferencing languages are able to figure out the types for similar expressions using the Hindley-Milner type system, so its definitely not impossible.

Comment: @Juliet: well, C# isn't exactly a purely functional language like Haskell, so its type system has some limitations that others might not have. Quite honestly: I find "var" a bit disturbing, in 99% of the cases, it wouldn't be any problem at all to *know* what the type is and spell it out - which I find better - your intent gets across clearer, and it's easier to maintain such code. Don't overuse "var" !

Answer (score 1):

Because c# is type safe and **strong** type language. At any place of your program compiler always knows the type of argument you are using. `var` keyword was just introduced to have variables of anonymus types.

Comment: those variables aren't of "anonymous" type - they have a well-defined, strong type - you just don't bother to specify and let the compiler figure it out...

Comment: Actually I was talking about the case when you cannot live without var keyword - e.g. you are declaring anonimous type with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Check `dynamic` in C# 4

Comment: What is new in dynamic.you mean it is possible in C#4 ?

Comment: how is "dynamic" going to help in this situation?? dynamic != variant!

Comment: @Wonde: No you still cannot use `var` like that in C# 4, but C# 4 introduces dynamic types which means that binding is done at runtime instead of at compile time.

Comment: @marc_s @wonde new keyword staying behind dynamic types. of course it's not the same. And mechanics behind is different, however it can be used in some cases which i suppose was looked for. You can create a method with dynamic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Type inference is type inference, either in local expressions or global / interprocedural. So it isn't about "not having a right hand side", because in compiler theory, a procedure call is a form of "right hand side".

C# could do this if the compiler did global type inference, but it does not.

You can use "object" if you want a parameter that accepts anything, but then you need to deal with the runtime conversion and potential exceptions yourself.

"var" in C# isn't a runtime type binding, it is a compile time feature that ends up with a very specific type, but C# type inference is limited in scope.